# Array is printing with weird question mark symbols when printing fibonacci sequences

Tags: c, arrays, symbols, fibonacci

When printing each Fibonacci sequence the first couple of sequences print in weird symbols or not at all if printing more than 8 sequences.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//n=amount of numbers in the series to compute, seq=array to store series
void fibonacci(int n, int* seq){
    // Complete this function
    int i;
    seq[0] = 0;
    seq[1] = 1;
    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        seq[i] = seq[i-2] + seq[i-1];
    }



}

int main(){

    int n;
    //n, amount of series to compute
    scanf("%d",&n);

    //initialize array to 1, using malloc/calloc
    int *seq = malloc(1 * sizeof(*seq));

    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){

            //recompute the whole series
            fibonacci(i, seq);

        //print array
            int j;
            for(j = 0; j < i; j++)/* complete code */
            printf("%d ", seq[j]);

        //resize array, with realloc
            int newSize=i+1;
        int *seq = realloc(seq, newSize);

        printf("\n");
    }
    //free array
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
"7Y��yb�=

Um�*/E�o 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946
```

Comment: On the first iteration, `seq` can hold one value in `seq[0]`, but you try to store two values into it (in `seq[1]` too); this leads to great unhappiness, diamonds etc in your output and questions on SO.  Why not simply allocate `(n + 1) * sizeof(*seq)` bytes and forget the reallocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different problems in your code:

1. In your `fibonacci()` function, you iterate using `i <= n`, but inside the loop, you assign to `seq[i]`. When `i` = `n`, this becomes a problem: you're accessing one cell out of the array.
2. You are getting `n` from user input, but then doing `int *seq = malloc(1 * sizeof(*seq))`. You are only allocating space for one element, not `n`. You should do `malloc(n * sizeof(*seq))` instead.
3. Not really an error, but inside the first `for` loop in your `main`, you're both re-defining and re-allocating the `seq` array with `int *seq = realloc(...)`. That is not needed at all. Your array is already `n` cells big, so there is no need to reallocate it each time. You can use it as is.
4. Not really an error, but there is no need to recompute the series each time. You can compute it only once and then partially print it on each row without a problem.

Also, **IMPORTANT!** Using `int` to hold numbers of the Fibonacci sequence is only good until you reach `n = 47`. More than that, and your next element will overflow the maximum positive value that an `int` can hold, turning negative, and invalidating the rest of the calculations too. I would suggest you to use `long long unsigned int` instead, which would be good up to `n = 94` (assuming 64 bits). Ultimately, you should check the value of `n` before calculating the Fibonacci sequence to avoid an overflow.

---

Here's a better version of your code with those problems fixed:

```
void fibonacci(int n, int* seq) {
    int i;

    seq[0] = 0;
    seq[1] = 1;

    for(i = 2; i < n; i++)
        seq[i] = seq[i-2] + seq[i-1];
}

int main() {
    int *seq;
    int n, i, j;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    // Allocate enough space for n elements:
    seq = malloc(n * sizeof(*seq));

    // Compute the whole series once:
    fibonacci(n, seq);

    // Print partial series on each row:
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
            printf("%d ", seq[j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    free(seq);

    return 0;
}
```